# iOS: Invalid registration token. Check the token format

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am new for Firebase as well as for iOS. I am trying to send push notification using FCM.

I registered an iOS app on FCM. Both `.p12` certificates added. Code developed according to FCM.

While sending notification through the [Firebase Console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device), I'm getting the error `Invalid registration token. Check the token format.`. I don't what mistake I did.

[image: FCM Console]

Comment: Can you post the relevant code for sending the message?

Comment: I followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) tutorial

Comment: @ShreejayPendse i am facing same error.how you solve issue.and what i have to add in single device.device token?

Comment: How did you solve this ?

Comment: I was facing the same error getting `instanceId` instead of `token`. Just mixed things up.
Ensure you are getting exactly token

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To solve the this issue

I followed complete tutorial of **FCM** provided for iOS. But while testing or implementing I used **APN Server**.
While using APN Server you need only *.pem* file

For reference this is my `.py` file code

```
import random
from apns import APNs, Frame, Payload

sound = "default"
badge = None
alert = "Message"
identifier = random.getrandbits(32)

apns_enhanced = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='vendor.pem', enhanced=True)
payload = Payload(alert=alert, sound=sound, badge = badge)
apns_enhanced.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex_office, payload, identifier=identifier)
apns_enhanced.gateway_server.force_close()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

There are two tokens you get at iOS side

1. Token generated by iOS which is received in method `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`
2. Token generated by Firebase `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()` (this you can print in AppDelegate)

The issue you are facing is because firebase console portal requires token received by way 2 and you are using token received by way 1.

Comment: could you please read my question? I am trying to fix this error for days. Many thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359010

Comment: FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() has now changed to InstanceID.instanceID().token()

Comment: I am facing this issue when I create a release build debug build is fine for me even I have uploaded the p12 certificate for both prod and dev environment ?  Can you help