# FCM: Invalid registration token. Check the token format

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I’m implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) and am experiencing a problem that I’m unable to solve. I have implemented `FirebaseMessagingService` and `FirebaseInstanceIdService` according to the guide(s). When I go to Firebase Console for my app, and use the Notification function, I can successfully send a message to ALL my app instances (using the package name).

Now, in the code I have fetched the Firebase Instance Id (token) by use of the following code:

```
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    SendFirebaseTokenToServer(token);
```

(note that currently I’m using HTTP protocol, as my server does not yet have a cert). Anyway using the token I get from the call above, I go back to the Firebase Console and try to send a message to one (1) installed instance of my app. I grab the token from our server DB where it is stored as "varchar(max)". When I do that I get the following error message:

```
Invalid registration token. Check the token format.
```

I have googled that and found only one hit (having to do with Firebase and iOS):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343520/ios-invalid-registration-token-check-the-token-format
```

That issue indicates that a cert was required (I think I’m reading it correctly). I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong. I need to get this to work using the Firebase Console first, then my server guy can start on his end knowing that it should work.

Comment: Ok, i decided to try the Firebase Console directly (no server interaction) using the registration_id (token) i got from the Firebase call (spit out to Logcat). It worked! so the problem exists either on the server or in my sending it to the server. should i Encode() the token?

Comment: If the problem exists in the code in your app server, edit your question to include the [minimal server code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing that code, it'll be hard to say what's wrong with it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  I am facing the same issue for the past few days. Could you please read my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359010

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i was programatically encoding all POST or PUT parameters prior to sending to our server. the FCM token had a semicolon in it, which got encoded to a "%3A", seemingly causing the problem.

do NOT encode the FCM token.

Comment: Faced the exact same issue what i suggest here is you should encode FCM token specially when passing in query string and then on server side apply url decoding on it.